# Does youtube data Api cost any quota for watching a video?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

In my Android app, I am using youtube data API for playing videos. How much does it cost for a video to play (say a 30 minutes video)? I have checked this uses limit in my cloud console but it is showing no uses yet( but users of my app is playing videos for more than 10 days). Explain this to me in an easy way as I am new to youtube data API.

Comment: Hi @bhaskar I am wondering the same. Do you have an answer if watching videos costs quota or not?

Comment: No watching videos does not cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Youtube data api doesn't play videos it allows you to upload videos, search for videos ....

The quota cost of making a request against the API is the cost against your projects quota allotment that you have in google developer console it is not a monitory cost.  [Quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

That being said if you want to extend your quota and google approves it they may charge you for the extension.

Again Quota cost has nothing to do with money.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. It means no limit for playing videos. Is it right?